# Matlab - Save the 32x32 centre of an imread image

Tags: matlab, crop

So I'm reading in a bunch of images in Matlab.

The section of the image I'm interested in, is the central 32x32 most pixels (a small square in the centre of the actual image).

Once you've read the image in, how can I extract just a centre piece or 32x32 and store it in a new image variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your image a 2D or a 3D array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your images aren't RGB, this could be slightly simpler, but why not cover the more complex case:

```
img = imread('image.png');
sz = size(img);
x = floor(sz(2)/2);
y = floor(sz(1)/2);
patch = img(y-15:y+16, x-15:x+16, :);
```

Comment: Oh nice. For some reason I thought it would be more complex than that. Thanks :D Out of curiosity, how does it differ if they're not RGB? Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Reanimation If the image is a 2D array (for example, a gray-scale image) you can remove `, :` in the last line, as there isn't a third dimension in that case

Comment: Also, in the 2D case I prefer to use `[y x] = size(...)` to avoid the intermediate vector - you end up with pretty much the same amount of code either way so whether it's really 'simpler' is debatable.